# how to get httponly cookie in php?

Tags: php, cookies, cookie-httponly

I want to set an HttpOnly cookie from my PHP server. According to the [PHP Cookie Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) I should just use the 7th parameter of `setcookie` method to set an http only cookie.

this is my code:

```
$key = 'abcdefg';
$expires = strtotime('+3 hours');
setcookie('mykey', $key, $expires, '/', 'myexample.com', false, true);
echo 'mykey' . $_COOKIE['mykey'];
```

but the result is an error message `undefined index: mykey`. what am I doing wrong??

Comment: `http` is not a valid input parameter for `setcookie()`. That should be a boolean value. You also have to reload the page before it's accessible in the `$_COOKIE` variable.

Comment: just tried changing the 6th param to false. still the same error..

Comment: Reload the page, once cookies have been set they can be accessed on the next page load.

Comment: so that's it?? I can't believe I forgot about it. I think I need to go back to learn PHP for dummies from start.. thanks @Daan.